# Breeze EntityQuery results do not honor projection with select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

When executing a Breeze entityQuery using projection with a .select, the result set still returns every property instead of only those selected, even though the httpresponse only contains the properties in the select.

```
                query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from('MyClass')
                .select('name,code,id')
                .skip(0)
                .take(20);

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (resp) { 
                return resp.results;   
            })
            .catch(function (error) { 
                return error;
            });
```

the httpResponse contains instances with only name, code, and id.....However, the results contains every property for the entity with only those values populated as well as the entityAspect. I was under the impression that the a projection query would contain POJO objects rather than full Breeze entities:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/knockout-circular-references

"Construct a query using a select clause that names just the property values you'll display in your grid (plus the entity key so you can get the full entity later when you need to).

A projection query returns JavaScript objects with raw property values."

The issue in the above link is the reason that I am attempting this. I need to bind to a kendo grid (though using AngularJS bindings rather than Knockout).

Thanks!!

Comment: Something isn't adding up for me - whenever I use select it works great and does exactly what you are mentioning that it should.  I don't have any samples I can reproduce this in right now but could you add which version of Breeze you are using?

Comment: using 1.4.9....so when you add a select clause to an entityquery, it will return POJOs?

Comment: Yep.  I use it mainly with Knockout though.  If you could create a fiddle or something similar to reproduce the issue that may be helpful in figuring out what may be wrong.  As a note the current version is 1.4.14 so I would try upgrading and see if maybe there was an issue with the version you are using.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce based on what you've said (using a northwind model).  Posting a fiddle would be helpful.